# Put a title of plot inside a for loop

Tags: r, loops, plot, title

I have a code with a nested `for` loop that runs perfect and gives me 4X4 plots in a page. I need to insert the title in each plot. Below is my code.

What I wanted to do is create a vector and assign my titles inside it, as shown in code and then read it inside loop. For that, I need to convert the index i into number and use the position of second vector.

This is my approach which may not be that good so either you can use mine or give your own idea. You can play with any random datasets and use simple plot/histogram. The vectors represent the day of week and time of day respectively.

```
#set dimension
par(mfcol=c(4,4))

#vector definition
days<-c(1,2,3,4)
hours<-c(8,14,18,22)

#Title vector
D1<-c("Monday (7-8 am)","Monday (1-2 pm)","Monday (5-6 pm)",
  "Monday (9-10 pm)")
D2<-c("Wednesday (7-8 am)","Wednesday (1-2 pm)","Wednesday (5-6 pm)",
  "Wednesday (9-10 pm)")
D3<-c("Friday (7-8 am)","Friday (1-2 pm)","Friday (5-6 pm)",
  "Friday (9-10 pm)")
D4<-c("Saturday (7-8 am)","Saturday (1-2 pm)","Saturday (5-6 pm)",
  "Saturday (9-10 pm)")

#Loop
for (i in days)
{
  for (j in hours)
  {
    # set positioning of the histogram
    par("plt" = c(0.2,0.95,0.35,0.84))
    # plot the histogram
    hist(path$TT[path$days==i & path$hours==j], breaks =     seq(0,60,by=3), xlab="Travel Time",
         ylab="Number of paths",col="blue", **main=D??**, mgp=c(2.5,1,0))

  }
}
```

## here is data sample-> dput(path)

```
structure(list(days = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), hours = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L), TT = c(34.82720833, 
34.13870083, 30.59218805, 35.1616205, 34.87982204, 30.74262596, 
35.19981237, 35.14235172, 31.6716496, 29.84148401, 31.32268062, 
30.58250275, 35.26514263, 33.55230269, 34.97001136, 31.09735713, 
29.90509108, 33.78335499, 33.08419061, 33.9702478, 32.68267307, 
32.88848951, 30.16693345, 32.85994732, 30.83277565, 34.62568305, 
34.13923292, 33.50498645, 31.31095608, 34.31001321, 33.99902318, 
33.7909643, 34.33340843, 32.30046602, 34.74999297, 29.87097318, 
32.91255436, 30.37869556, 35.22453148, 33.91415576, 30.87027627, 
34.32036758, 34.14405484, 32.52770687, 30.63412371, 30.69590367, 
34.10350198, 33.51383263, 31.19792969, 35.26664132, 33.79975778, 
30.9254123, 33.58382797, 32.47180323, 35.07275967, 30.97518331, 
34.09754282, 31.30283331, 35.03617718, 35.0447385, 34.48088429, 
34.93546837, 30.97837093, 31.14469741, 30.92743268, 34.10879646, 
30.4886625, 35.00307314, 31.41065689, 31.82113768, 30.38511722, 
30.39628127, 31.89778508, 31.5036342, 30.78847263, 30.63294595, 
34.40494811, 32.57036077, 31.96399169, 33.90064885, 31.64029012, 
34.1366935, 35.24047602, 30.50038163, 35.26178882, 30.67850437, 
31.28041078, 31.13586861, 34.03564851, 30.45301463, 31.46075363, 
32.79463877, 34.37256141, 31.14590299, 32.98806056, 34.61871373, 
34.50000295, 33.64822723, 31.79305995, 32.95337037, 31.97535842, 
33.01756184, 30.27499142, 31.52636985, 33.88390737, 29.86033691, 
33.10717421, 31.13912362, 34.03308637, 29.82060846, 30.29160216, 
30.68720702, 32.21043532, 32.38637581, 29.87286573, 31.91229798, 
33.07799897, 30.41662694, 32.24261367, 35.3258724, 29.81198078, 
29.87369792, 29.5469277, 31.07479327, 29.93749303, 31.32897414, 
32.11042476, 31.74139691, 29.35309499, 31.91510643, 28.43111183, 
30.64316778, 28.82045246, 31.2966231, 32.88217249, 28.85142648, 
32.61772627, 28.89998879, 29.09439029, 31.17275104, 30.14374991, 
32.54361297, 30.50674627, 32.01595442, 30.50549694, 30.92120556, 
28.56600115, 32.6272292, 32.01189691, 32.48467475, 32.63696512, 
30.92335971, 31.05045202, 30.7754939, 31.40027579, 29.12356583, 
31.77973836, 28.78119827, 31.44082345, 30.73383322, 32.04126499, 
30.09865077, 32.23577216, 29.08265343, 30.49423226, 31.46262176, 
29.84828538, 30.18785884, 29.51834908, 29.37202672, 31.50806652, 
32.40830835, 30.48030326, 31.25898945, 28.36670284, 31.28059981, 
29.34232677, 30.09806882, 32.11127774, 29.59171523, 30.61713837, 
29.76958526, 31.85824615, 32.16215903, 29.84655136, 31.07721122, 
28.65494456, 30.9843114, 32.54863022, 31.46634971, 31.89779842, 
32.82481805, 32.14782935, 32.08964421, 31.60785849, 32.91857557, 
31.71183437, 31.81246841, 32.98599723, 28.95747656, 28.84662181, 
31.71611474, 31.62086303, 32.53920721, 30.42499004, 28.99300588, 
29.61203445, 32.4920689, 29.36255767, 32.6194317, 31.04202451, 
28.75123245, 30.13704325, 30.92045914, 32.57753631, 30.83279548, 
28.8546849, 30.74245368, 29.03716971, 28.37275181, 30.86814322, 
30.61960665, 30.42719574, 30.27684903, 32.91275304, 29.80632759, 
29.50108563, 32.6131215, 30.03530353, 30.24898855, 29.97890411, 
29.91508311, 30.66431902, 29.44062756, 30.78040092, 30.42641885, 
32.52252736, 32.02849124, 28.44168133, 28.77193919, 32.3661733, 
32.50081923, 30.78754405, 29.31429942, 29.25319403, 29.41670938, 
34.79250707, 28.45292865, 33.30658009, 36.95793072, 31.1241599, 
29.47446652, 37.93368226, 29.99169743, 34.53286071, 33.30080173, 
32.07298455, 34.59538339, 33.19895485, 32.39419483, 31.37985584, 
33.10293436, 29.39098815, 29.6792889, 35.03296983, 37.90584009, 
30.95003357, 33.20300797, 37.19244019, 35.17202829, 33.36301054, 
35.45811104, 32.30603702, 35.90719466, 32.53788221, 32.98462237, 
34.40384647, 34.60599035, 36.12782575, 34.22463048, 29.98624712, 
35.806683, 36.85504472, 35.98104837, 35.97362738, 35.43026929, 
29.52289309, 29.0544412, 28.38438112, 29.31043103, 34.55714132, 
31.35110246, 35.45463173, 32.52063466, 29.64833452, 31.74827447, 
31.19599864, 35.86874035, 31.36035725, 30.90048731, 36.67327499, 
30.0504123, 37.41148645, 33.68205359, 29.2592527, 28.82514246, 
30.62364715, 37.55578321, 32.25899523, 34.31735337, 37.1286007, 
30.09667053, 37.77301539, 37.28325032, 33.82381014, 33.64911154, 
32.23733708, 35.36476734, 31.19880018, 29.1404291, 30.72636631, 
34.77003685, 37.31098961, 31.55246022, 28.51524079, 35.97250119, 
35.08409392, 36.5458489, 37.35540297, 30.23406879, 29.17387163, 
33.74088357, 29.40765925, 29.98726349, 29.58959745, 31.96605073, 
31.94788415, 33.60347166, 28.43148601, 29.65454367, 36.06816061, 
29.96597865, 31.90935292, 28.59771444, 32.44428733, 31.50734498, 
30.23029062, 32.7213003, 33.17963215, 30.84546259, 35.61594726, 
31.1375163, 33.58903731, 36.3755896, 30.15521544, 32.64832733, 
29.75419547, 32.87727257, 32.86349263, 30.87051665, 34.99052692, 
29.32459293, 29.75063939, 29.31336196, 30.26155711, 37.78471798, 
29.29637466, 33.63983534, 29.0707227, 37.23740461, 30.46483145, 
32.5191104, 32.38759822, 35.67256593, 31.96392716, 33.3250217, 
35.46341363, 28.75439972, 33.2611733, 30.02014914, 35.78496489, 
32.96781502, 31.43534921, 35.07596123, 34.52762462, 30.26655854, 
35.32014083, 37.55183466, 34.14971103, 36.29105196, 32.40044715, 
36.0587327, 31.83769864, 33.92873059, 34.70263617, 30.80816039, 
30.68630199, 31.01802064, 30.80777532, 35.05333618, 27.06058834, 
27.79241831, 27.33752079, 27.77903509, 26.947812, 27.8862964, 
27.39365377, 27.9236377, 26.78983708, 27.98767273, 27.93024624, 
27.84690108, 27.32830243, 26.81574528, 27.11055277, 27.39296015, 
28.00610613, 27.71688355, 27.62271524, 27.69926561, 26.77071774, 
26.75407601, 27.54772857, 26.85613667, 27.43762662, 27.45478206, 
27.70204762, 27.66985159, 27.46593956, 28.00153523, 27.85391116, 
26.78324156, 27.51476443, 27.54375831, 27.45536832, 27.25299275, 
27.42563343, 27.35861323, 27.89703515, 27.94359525, 27.02701474, 
28.01213784, 27.05632904, 27.219231, 28.00160216, 27.06621867, 
26.83356071, 26.85138171, 26.9857268, 26.84488214, 27.04212578, 
27.90226659, 26.88270484, 27.36445874, 27.98903653, 26.74879158, 
27.91409337, 27.04442553, 27.76393403, 26.97261286, 26.82558533, 
27.40286709, 26.90959192, 27.61358064, 27.67649126, 27.98923329, 
27.27538051, 27.93429854, 27.24070111, 27.79609001, 27.51659686, 
27.60029289, 26.85518925, 27.31821322, 27.1642527, 27.27570585, 
27.67152235, 26.96014272, 27.89962397, 27.84824436)), .Names = c("days", 
"hours", "TT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -480L
))
```

Comment: Could you post your data with dput(dataframe) so that we know what it looks like? It would help in producing an example.

Comment: here is the format of my data and made a slight change in code, to depict a more real case. you can add your random data in hours (1-24) and travel time columns with days (1-5). sorry, posting data in dput format is not working      head(path)
  days hours       TT
1    1     7 34.82721
2    2     7 34.13870
3    3     7 30.59219
4    4     7 35.16162
5    5     7 34.87982
6    1     7 30.74263

Comment: @be_green:just posted in dput format

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have 4*4=16 plots, with 16 titles in 4 vectors.
Try this argument in your function,

`main=get(paste0("D",i))[which(hours==j)]`

`get()`function can get the object with the given object name.

I use some simulated data, just to check the titles. Looks good,
[image]
Sample codes:

    `x<-rnorm(50)#my simulated data
    for (i in days)
    {
       for (j in hours)
       {
            hist(x,xlab="Travel Time",
                ylab="Number of paths",col="blue",
                main=get(paste0("D",i))[which(hours==j)], mgp=c(2.5,1,0))
        }
    }`

Comment: code looks good but it is not running. shows this-
Error in get(paste0("D", i, "[", which(hours == j), "]")) : 
  object 'D1[1]' not found

Comment: One minor bug, just fixed it. I can run it without problems.

Comment: Plot and code attached. Thank you for pointing the error out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks great!

Answer (score 0):

This is revised to match the data that was provided.

The main idea here is to make a matrix of the titles and simply access the matrix each time you print.  The code in the question looped through hours and days. Because I want to know the index, I have change this to looping through the indices, 1:4. That means that where the original code used the loop variable  (hours or days) I use the index to select elements from hours or days.

I am assuming that we already have the data.frame and the OP's lists D1, D2, D3 and D4.

```
LabelMat = matrix(c(D1, D2, D3, D4), nrow=4)

for (i in 1:4)  {
  for (j in 1:4)  {
    # set positioning of the histogram
    par("plt" = c(0.2,0.95,0.35,0.84))
    # plot the histogram
    hist(path$TT[path$days==days[i] & path$hours==hours[j]], breaks = seq(0,60,by=3), 
        xlab="Travel Time", ylab="Number of paths", 
        col="blue", main = LabelMat[i,j], mgp=c(2.5,1,0))
  }
}
```

[image: Labeled Histograms]

Comment: you are in right direction. but vector of j is not 1:4, instead different number which I have posted in question. Can you please revise your code accordingly? i made small change in hist() and posted a dataframe. might be helpful. Thanks!